# Is a space metric on the positive real numbers not complete?

Tags: metric-spaces

Say we have a metric space $(\mathbb{R}^+, d)$

where the distance function is

$d(x,y) = |x - y| + | 1/x - 1/y |$

Then I argue that this metric space is not complete: If we look at the Cauchy sequence $1/x$, which is contained in the metric space, we see that the limit of the sequence $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$ is not in the metric space. Hence, the metric space is not complete.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a valid argument/proof?

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}$ has to be interpreted in terms of the metric $d$ and not in terms of the usual metric on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Is there a straightforward way to see that $d$ is a metric?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your proof has a serious flaw: The sequence $\frac{1}x$ is not Cauchy in this metric space. Note that (for $x,y\in \mathbb N$)
$$d(1/x,1/y)=|x-y| + |1/x - 1/y| > |x-y| \geq 1$$
This means that there can be no $N$ such that $d(1/x,1/y)<1$ for all $x,y>N$, contradicting that it is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Thanks Milo, I guess I just have a very poor idea of how the distance function should be interpreted in relation to the metric space itself. This helped me to get a better picture of it :)

Answer (score 11):

**Milo Brandt** has shown what is wrong with your argument. In fact $\langle\Bbb R^+,d\rangle$ *is* complete. Here’s a hint outlining how you might prove that.

HINT: Suppose that $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $\langle\Bbb R^+,d\rangle$ is $d$-Cauchy.

- Show that $\sigma$ is Cauchy in the Euclidean metric, and conclude that $\sigma$ converges to some $x\in\Bbb R$ in the Euclidean metric.
- Show that $x\ge 0$.
- Show that if $x$ were $0$, $\sigma$ wouldn’t be Cauchy after all.
- Show that if $x>0$, $\sigma$ converges to $x$ in the metric $d$ as well as in the Euclidean metric.
- Put the pieces together to conclude that $\langle\Bbb R^+,d\rangle$ is complete.

Comment: Thanks! A lot more work than i imagined though. Can you tell me why the Euclidean metric is of any interest in relation to this metric?

Comment: @Fredrik: You’re welcome. Basically the metric $d$ is a way to adjust the Euclidean metric just enough to get one that is complete on $\Bbb R^+$. Notice that $d(x,y)$ and $|x-y|$ are very nearly the same when $x$ and $y$ are large; it’s only when you get near $0$ that $d(x,y)$ and $|x-y|$ differ greatly, and that difference is carefully arranged so that sequences that converge to $0$ in the usual metric are no longer Cauchy. But $d$ is still enough like the Euclidean metric to generate the same topology.

Comment: @Fredrik You can actually get that this metric is just the Euclidean metric in disguise - consider the map $f(x) = x - \frac{1}x$. You can prove that $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$. This observation lets you lift basically every property (for instance, completeness) of $\mathbb R$ (with the usual metric) to the new metric space.

Comment: @Brian: That is a very good explanation and I think it is a smart strategy :) With some work, I am now confident that I will be able to make a solid proof of it being complete. Thanks a lot Brian!